# How to iterate over this hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I have this hash with a specfic array in it:

```
@infodata = {}
@infodata[:titles] = Array.new([])
```

And I want to store it in a CSV file, like this:

```
CSV.open("infodata.csv", "wb") do |csv|
 @infodata.values
end
```

The output I get is this:

```
avancerad,Ingen examen,uh,ArkivvetenskapArchival science,HIA80D,10.300,uoh,"Arkivvetenskap rör villkoren för befintliga arkiv och modern arkivbildning med fokus på arkivarieyrkets arbetsuppgifter: bevara, tillgängliggöra och styra information. Under ett år behandlas bl a informations- och dokumenthantering, arkivredovisning, gallring, lagstiftning och arkivteori. I kursen ingår praktik, där man under handledning får arbeta med olika arkivarieuppgifter.",statlig,60
```

The output I want is this:

```
avancerad,Ingen examen,uh,Arkivvetenskap, Archival science,HIA80D,10.300,uoh,"Arkivvetenskap rör villkoren för befintliga arkiv och modern arkivbildning med fokus på arkivarieyrkets arbetsuppgifter: bevara, tillgängliggöra och styra information. Under ett år behandlas bl a informations- och dokumenthantering, arkivredovisning, gallring, lagstiftning och arkivteori. I kursen ingår praktik, där man under handledning får arbeta med olika arkivarieuppgifter.",statlig,60
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are trying to do here but there's a chance that

```
CSV.open("infodata.csv", "wb") do |csv|
  @infodata.values.flatten
end
```

could do the trick.

Comment: You sir are awesome! What does flatten do?

Comment: Flatten: Returns a new array that is a one-dimensional flattening of this hash. That is, for every key or value that is an array, extract its elements into the new array.